# UITableView Section Header Change Style of Current Header

Tags: ios, uitableview

Does anyone know of a built in method or custom way to access and change styles of the CURRENT section header in a UITableView (style plain) as the UITableView is scrolled in Swift.

My preset style for the header is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView //recast your view as a UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold", size: 14)
    header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor()
    header.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
}
```

Specifically I would like to change the header background color to black and the text color to white only for the current section header as the view scrolls. The style for other headers remain in the preset style.

Answer (score 1):

In a current Application of mine:

```
override public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
    let view: UIView
    if let _view: UIView = tableView.headerViewForSection(section)
    {
        view = _view
    } else {
        let dxOffset: CGFloat = 16.0
        view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(dxOffset, 0, tableView.frame.size.width - dxOffset, TableViewViewsHeight.sectionHeight))
    }

    // create our label
    let label: UILabel = UILabel(frame: view.frame)
    label.textColor = UIColor.appEmptyTextColor()
    label.text = "\(self.letters[section])"
    label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.smallSystemFontSize() + 4.0)

    // create the separator frame
    var separatorFrame: CGRect = view.frame
    separatorFrame.size = CGSizeMake(separatorFrame.size.width, 1.0)
    separatorFrame.offset(dx: 0.0, dy: view.frame.size.height - 1.0)

    // create the separator
    let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: separatorFrame)
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.appEmptyGolfTrainingTextColor()
    imageView.alpha = 0.4

    // add subviews
    view.addSubview(label)
    view.addSubview(imageView)

    // setup the view
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    return view
}
```

This creates a header with a white background, a separator and a label containing a letter.

You should be using `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` to change the appearance of your section header.

Comment: This is simply code to style a header. Could you please submit an example on how to change the style of the current section header dynamically as the view scrolls through different sections. I would like the header that is sticking to the top of the table view to have different styles than the rest of the headers below it.

Comment: you mean while the content is scrolled?

Comment: yes. as the content scrolls. each header that becomes the current section header (sticking to top of tableview) takes on a custom style while it is sticking to the top of the tableview

Comment: this is interesting. subscribing!